# Android FileObserver not calling onEvent in USB mass storage mode

Tags: android, inotify, usb-mass-storage, fileobserver

I have FileObserver's hooked onto a particular directory in /mnt/sdcard/X and its descendants recursively. When I modify contents of this directory from the phone itself (say from the Gallery app), the onEvent() of my FileObserver is correctly called and everything works fine.

When I connect via USB to a computer and switch to mass storage mode, all changes done via the computer to the same directory are not translated to events to the FileObserver. Is there a limitation on the FileObserver that it will not work in USB mass storage?

I tried an 'adb push xx /mnt/sdcard/X/xx' and this change gets recorded correctly too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a limitation on the FileObserver that it will not work in USB mass storage?

*Nothing* in Android works with external storage when it is mounted via USB Mass Storage (Android 1.x/2.x). The external storage is exclusively owned by the OS that has it mounted. You will not get `FileObserver` events while the storage is so mounted.

Android 3.0+ uses the Media Transfer Protocol (MTP) instead of USB Mass Storage, and so `FileObserver` should work with external storage on newer versions of Android, even while another OS has access to that storage.

Comment: Ok, got it. I assume MEDIA_MOUNTED is broadcast once USB storage is turned off, is that correct?

Comment: @NarendraAcharya: Yes, AFAIK.